# ExcelVBA - Pulling data from website that has dropdown and dynamically create link to download file

Tags: web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I am trying to pull data from site https://www.niftyindices.com/reports/historical-data. On this site there are 3 dropdowns, once relevant values are selected and "submit" button is clicked it generates file to download data.

I have written macro code to populate value in first dropdown but not able to select values in two other dropdown. Also, not able to figure out how to get link to file that is dynamically created. Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is half complete code -

```
Sub website_data()
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDcoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim changeEvent As Object

Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.niftyindices.com/reports/historical-data"

Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Loop
Set HTMLDcoc = IE.document

'This will select 1st dropdown
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDcoc.getElementById("HistoricalMenu")
HTMLInput.Click
HTMLDcoc.querySelector("[class=""form4""]").Click

'This will select 2st dropdown
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDcoc.getElementById("ddlHistoricaldivtypee") 
HTMLInput.Value = "Equity"
'HTMLInput.selectedIndex = 2 
Set changeEvent = HTMLDcoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
changeEvent.initEvent "change", True, False
HTMLDcoc.getElementById("ddlHistoricaldivtypee").dispatchEvent changeEvent
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

'This will populate 2nd dropdown and select value
Set HTMLInput =     HTMLDcoc.getElementById("ddlHistoricaldivtypeeindex") 
HTMLInput.Value = "NIFTY 50" 

'having difficulty in selection date. Here is the image -
```

[when user clicks the calendar image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGknx.png)

The HTML code (after clicking the calendar)
[Month, year and date selection HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnpMW.png)